# Will Ubuntu 12.04's proprietary AMD/ATI driver be updated to 12.5, 12.6, etc. once released?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, radeon, ati

I've decided to install the proprietary AMD/ATI driver in Ubuntu 12.04 repo, but before I do so, I'd like to know:

Will Ubuntu 12.04's proprietary AMD/ATI driver be updated to 12.5, 12.6, etc. once AMD releases them?

And if so, should I install "fglrx" or "fglrx-updates" ( I think this is the post release update ) one?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK they don't update the Hardware drivers until the next Release.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that they would. I guess they wanted to keep it stable.

Comment: @UriHerrera: not true. This has been the case until Precise, but the fglrx-updates "post-install drivers" are precisely to fill this game: it was supposed to be always-updated drivers, like a PPA.

Comment: @MestreLion The FGLRX version in the Ubuntu repositories in precise is 8.960 including the fglrx-updates package, the version of the AMD drivers (12.4) is 8.961, so no they don't update the drivers.

Comment: They didn't update *yet*. And they probably won't for minor releases. They will probably package 12.5 when that is released, probably a few days/weeks after it.

Comment: @UriHerrera: They may skip some releases, perhaps packaging every 2~3 months. Which is still far better and more updated than the previous approach of "stuck with the same drivers from launch date, for years"

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I installed `fglrx` and `fglrx-amdcccle` via Jockey aka "Additional Hardware GUI app".

Everything seems to be working ok.

Packages in the Ubuntu 12.04 repo (2012-05-08):

```
fglrx
version: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1
size: 118 MB

fglrx-updates:
version: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1
size: 118 MB

fglrx-amdcccle:
version: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1
size: 11.5 MB

fglrx-amdcccle-updates:
version: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1
size: 11.5 MB
```

So it looks like "fglrx" and "fglrx-updates" are the same thing.

Here are some bug reports about installing AMD/ATI driver via Jockey:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-common/+bug/873058
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/994371
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/949641

Hope this helps

Comment: If they are the same, I wonder why fglrx works for me but fglrx-updates doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had performance issues with opensource drivers with dualscreen and these "Additional Drivers" from jockey didn't accept dualscreen at all. Latest 12.4 directly from AMD's site works perfectly (so far...). I'm having HD4850.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. They've got a trend. 
I check the AMD page [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) and build/purge/reinstall using the AMD Wiki's [directions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29) when a new one comes out. Haven't had problems with the CCC and manual build so far.